# Overriding the width of a parent element

Tags: html, css

http://www.mysecretathens.gr/kulte_test/as_index.html

I am trying to override the width of `#kontainer` in my `<li>` list at the bottom. I want the `.nav3` list to be full width, 100% but I cant override the `700px` of the parent element, `#kontainer`

What can I do? I tried the `!important;` rule, but that didn't give me the results I wanted.

Comment: Please next time don't just post link to your site. Content of your site will change, and this question will not help futture visitors. Post your code, or in best case create jsfiddle with your problem.

Answer (score 0):

When specifying percentage width, it calculates based off the parent's width. So 100% of 700 is... 700.

You need to specify a pixel width if you want it to go over 700.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:**  You can get `.nav3` out of `#kontainer`

**Solution 2:**  You can add `position: absolute; left: 0;` to `.nav3` and then add some `margin-top` on `#footer` tu push it down.

Answer (score 0):

Width 100% means get 100% of the parent element that the child is inside. It actually does what you said it to do! You can get nav3 out of the #kontainer to take the 100% of the body element.

Comment: You are right Antonis. Well I was eager to find out if there is a way that you can override the parent element?

euxaristw gia to comment pantws ;)

Comment: With a quick google search found nothing relative. I think that it s not possible.. tpt filos (eimaste kammenoi omws oi ellhnes tetoia wra! les na fame kana ban me ta ellinika?) And nice site by the way

Answer (score 0):

I want the same thing, to override the parent width.
I'm developing a Joomla component

> `<div class="container mainbody">` //** width 1170px **//
>
> > > `<div>`some content`</div>`
> > >
> > > `<div>`some content`</div>`
>
> `</div>`

I don't want to change the width (1170px) of the outer div or .container class because it is default in Joomla template, which will take effect in every page if I change.

In my case, I only need a 100% width for some child div in my website's home page for some design.

What I did is add css in home page html file, since it will not call in other page.

> `<div class="container mainbody">`
>
> > > `<div class="container">`some content, width 1170px`</div>`
> > >
> > > `<div>`some content, width 100%`</div>`
>
> `</div>`
>
> `<style type="text/css">`
>
> > .mainbody
> >
> > {
> >
> > > > width:100% !important;
> >
> > }
>
> `</style>`

Answer (score 0):

For the div you want a full page width, you should use:

```
position: absolute;
left: 0px;
right 0px; //but make sure that any content you have below that div, gets margined in response.
margin-top: 200px; //Use the height of the above div
```

Comment: This doesnt work for me, it just aligns itself to the child container.

Answer (score -1):

I have just noticed a **"VERY"** interesting (and bold) way of overriding the parent element's width. Set the child's width to something like:

width: calc(100% + 30%);

Believe it or not, at least Firefox 51 is calculating correctly the child's width, and yes, it is bigger than the parent's width.